# In Spider-Man 3, why does MJ lie?

Tags: plot-explanation, spider-man-trilogy, spider-man-3

In *Spider-Man 3*, after the evil "Green Goblinish" side awakens in Harry Osbourne, he confronts Mary Jane Watson and tells her to break up with her fiancé, Peter Parker. She does so, telling him that she has fallen in love with another.

Why? Is she worrying for his safety, or her own? Couldn't she just as easily have said "watch out for Harry, he's the Green Goblin now. Protect me?" She knows that he's Spider-Man and has defeated the Green Goblin in the past.

Comment: May be she is concerned about Peter's safety. no matter he is being spider man, Harry is his best friend. and conflict with Harry may not be a good thing for peter. So MJ may have decided to just not be a part of breaking up the best friends

Comment: Because she loves being an actress? Great question though, why not just warn peter about it on the bridge and then act like she told him what Harry told her to? That would have been much safer for Peter if he has a heads up about it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay if you'll see that scene again you'll know she did it because of Peter's safety if she'd not done that Harry could've killed Peter, that's why **MJ lies to save Peter** 
And 
As I remember Harry was standing there (**near bridge or the meeting place of MJ and peter**) to see if  she'll tell Peter that Harry's threatening her.

Comment: If you could link to a video of the scene, that would make this answer even better.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It's correct, but doesn't address why she lied to Peter instead of warning him. What would Harry have done? There was no evidence of any danger on the bridge scene and Peter could have just gone to Harry's house (as he eventually did) and just address the issue then. I'm going to suggest it's more of MJ's state of mind more than anything.

Comment: This answer is correct within the movie's logic... this is the reason that the movie provides. However, I believe the OP is pointing out that this logic doesn't make sense, as Peter could have protected himself. I think really that just makes it a plot hole (the movie pretends this is the only way to keep Peter safe, when it clearly isn't).

Comment: But Harry didn't know that Peter is Spider-man That's a point too and maybe MJ too at that time

Comment: @GendoIkari: Whether Peter could protect himself or not is not relevant. What is relevant is whether MJ _believes_ Peter could protect himself. And also whether she wants to avoid infighting between Peter and Harry - if she speaks, she knowingly opens up the door of Harry turning violent. Regardless who started the conflict, MJ has no reason to want to further it.